# how does std::cout a null char* pointer abort the program?

Tags: c++, c++11

I try to print a nullptr to screen, and:

```
int* ptrA = nullptr;
std::cout<<ptrA<<"\n"; // print 0
char* ptrB = nullptr;
std::cout<<ptrB<<"\n"; // print nothing, program exit with code 0
... // never execute
```

I thought the compiler(g++ 4.8.4) may warning me that I should not try to cout a nullptr. the fact is: the program aborted, with '/test has exited with code 0 (0x00000000)', act like it terminals normally.

Why? I mean, if I do something wrong, or what does this designed to be?

thanks

---

thanks to all, I knew the behavior can be undefined,
for a char* to be a string, or to print the address.
And was adviced to never do this. 
I just wonder why the program didn't tell me anything, like warning, assert or exit with a code like -1, anything else. 
Is it the compiler's designed behavior?

Comment: The simple answer is, it's not a very high priority thing. C++ often errs on the side of assuming the programmer knows what they are doing and provides few training wheels. You may find thins interesting: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=16351 You might also read some articles on the difficulties of static analysis and false positives.

Comment: I bet it did exit with code -1 (or some other code)

Comment: To people who are directed by search engine to this page, you should read the answer from original "duplicated" question as stackoverflow hints. In brief, the program did exit with code 0 (i.e. SUCCESS). Although the [C++ standard requires that the `char*` pointer to be non-null](https://eel.is/c++draft/ostream.inserters.character), implementations generally do not just dereference it blindly, instead, they check the null-ness, and set `std::cout` to a "bad" state if `nullptr` is passed, so the following `opereator <<` won't be performed at all.

Answer (score 0):

`char*`s are the canonical string implementation in C, and unfortunately they are very common with C++ as well.

Due to that reason, outputting a `char*` will not output the address held by that pointer, but instead, it will print the *string* pointed by that pointer.

An implementation may look like this:

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const char* data)
{
  while (*data)
  {
    os << *data;
    data++;
  }
  return os;
}
```

Since it dereferences the pointer you give to it, passing a `(char*)nullptr)` to this function invokes undefined behaviour, and aborting is as good behaviour as any other in that case.

Comment: (Don't forget to `*data++`)

Comment: @Dúthomhas, oops, my bad

Comment: Did you mean to put a ++ in that loop?

Comment: @templatetypedef, what do you mean?

Comment: Never mind - you fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

When dealing with `ostream`, a `char*` is different from other kinds of pointers, because there is an `operator<<` specifically designed to treat a `char*` as a null-terminated C string.

Your program aborts because you are passing `operator<<` a `char*` pointer that:

- points to memory you do not own, or
- points to memory you do own, but is not a proper null-terminated C string, or
- is NULL

All of these things invoke **undefined behavior**, which means the compiler is being really nice to you by simply aborting your program instead of doing something horrid.

To print the value of a `char*` pointer, cast it to a `void*`.

Comment: You did not mention this in your list, but passing a NULL `char*` pointer to `operator<<` is *undefined behavior*, which can also lead to termination if `operator<<` dereferences it

Comment: It is not the *compiler* that aborts the program. More likely, invoking `operator<<` with invalid input is causing an exception to be thrown that is not being caught. An uncaught exception will call `std::terminate()`, and by default it calls `std::abort()` to abort the program.

Comment: LOL, simplifications for OP always get feedback. Yes, runtime is aborting program; I contend that runtime does what compiler designs it to do.